# Should I file an insurance claim for a door ding?

Tags: car, car-insurance

I purchased a new black sedan in January of this year.

A few months back, the car was keyed, and therefore I filed an insurance claim and to get it fixed.

Now, today, I find that the door has received as nice white ding on the passenger side door.
Should I file another claim?

What are the implications of making a second claim?
The deductible on the last claim was $50. I assume it will be the same this time.

I am a young driver with a pretty bad record. Any advice would be appreciated.

The car is just so new... and so it'd be nice to have it repaired..

Comment: Secondary question: How long do I have to file a claim?

Comment: What will the repair cost out of pocket?

Comment: My guess is a few hundred. I am not completely sure.

Comment: carrying a higher deductable could save you a lot on your annual rates, something you might want to consider.  a $50 deductable is generally pretty expensive.   And if you are not likely to file for smaller things anyway (to avoid raising the rate) then again, why have a low deductable?

Comment: Chuck, Thats not the normal deductible. It's a lower deductible for non-moving claims or something.

Comment: Just a thought, you'll find the audience here is very good at stretching their dollars, and cosmetics are expensive. If you were a real estate agent, I would consider getting it fixed at all costs (psychology is so important in business like that... impressions make a big deal!) If you work a 9-5, I'd just leave it. Buff it if you can, paint it or leave it if you can't. :)

Answer (score 10):

Find out what the repair will cost from a couple of ASE certified mechanics or other qualified people.  With that, figure that two claims in a short period of time will certainly raise your rates, (by how much isn't something I would know)

If the repair is something you can afford out of pocket, then pay for it out of pocket even if it stings a little bit.  Also, consider not repairing something that is strictly cosmetic and won't affect the vehicle down the line.

p.s.  A white ding sounds like something you can buff out, but please learn about polishing it out before you make a hole in your paint.

Answer (score 7):

Most insurers will think about booting you after 2-3 claims. I'd get it fixed out of pocket or leave it. If you're picky about your car, park in the back of the lot and avoid on-street parking.

Comment: And even if they don't boot you, they will certainly raise the premiums to a significantly higher level.  There is no free lunch.

Comment: +1 for the booting comment. **That** is the true risk, and then you have to find another insurance company to cover you, and likely pay even higher premiums.

Answer (score 4):

I think the hike in premiums isn't worth it. Just pay for this one yourself, and save insurance claims for bigger issues.

Answer (score 0):

For claims under a certain amount ($1500 sometimes, but this varies) there should not be an uptick in your insurance rate.  I imagine this is cumulative, so many of these might result in a premium increase.